# cvxopt: Trying to do LP and get "Terminated (singular KKT matrix)"

Tags: cvx, cvxpy

I am new to `cvxopt` and am trying to understand this fairly cryptic error message  "Terminated (singular KKT matrix)."  (At least critic for me.)

I am solving a linear program:
$$
\min c^Tx \\
s.t. Gx +s=h \\
Ax = b \\
s \ge 0
$$

,where $c=[-1,0,0,0,0,0]^T$, $h=0$, $A=[0,1,1,1,1,1]$, $b=1$. $G$ is slightly more involved:

$$G[0:5,0]=1 \\
0 \le G[0:5, 1:6] \le 1 \\
G[5:10,0]=0 \\
G[5:10,1:6]=-I_{5x5}
$$

I am checking to see if they meet the conditions required by `cvxopt.` What I know are:

1. $rank(A)=1$, which is automatically met.
2. $rank([A;G]) \ge n$ - I think this one is met, too
3. Each row of $A$ and $G$ need to be linearly independent? I am referring to

[the document here](http://www.acme.byu.edu/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Vol2Lab14.pdf). It is not true for this example, as the last few rows in $G$ are like $[0,-1,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,-1]$ but the row in $A$ is $[0,1,1,1,1,1]$I am not convinced that this need to be the case.

Anyway, I can successfully find solutions for problems formulated this way most of the time, but occasionally, cvxopt will iterate 5-7 times and abort with an error message "Terminated (singular KKT matrix)."

I think that this error message is not caused by the conditions listed above. But I am out of ideas to fix it. I want to know:

1. What does this error message mean? What causes it?
2. How can I try to fix it?

Comment: I noticed you tagged this question with CVXPY. Are you using CVXPY? If you are, I strongly recommend you don't use CVXOPT; you should use ECOS instead.

Comment: No, I am not using cvxpy. I tagged it only because there was no cvxopt tag.